# XCUITest detect UIView

Tags: xcode, uiview, automated-tests, xctest

So in XCUITest I use this code to get a button:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *button = app.buttons[@"button_identifier"];
```

getting a tableview using `app.tables` and image using `app.images` and so on.

But how can I get a view(UIView)?

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *customView = app.otherElements[@"view_identifier"];
```

Swift

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let customView = app.otherElements["view_identifier"]
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3 / 4 it would look like:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let custom_view = app.otherElements["view_identifier"]
```

Also what I like to do is to have a class variable, as I do reuse these views frequently for different tests:

```
lazy var custom_view: XCUIElement = { return XCUIApplication().otherElements["view_identifier"] }()
```